# Force Eclipse not to scan a directory

Tags: eclipse, samba

I would like to completely prevent Eclipse from trying to scan a directory of a project. Is that possible?

The reason is slightly complicated and arises due to several limiting factors:

- I work on Windows and cannot change that (not even dual-boot)
- I *can* use a virtual machine
- I work on a project that is inherently Linux-based
- The project uses svn (though I am considering accessing it with git-svn)
- The project has recursive symlinks and filenames that are invalid under fat/ntfs
- I have not been satisfied with the performance and stability of Eclipse under a VirtualBox-virtualized Ubuntu 12.10

As a result, I have tried to run Eclipse under Windows, and access the project and workspace via a samba share from the running virtualized Ubuntu. However, Eclipse chokes with dozens of errors while scanning the project tree due to invalid filenames, and a refresh never finishes due to recursive symlinks. Removing both of these locally solves the Eclipse problem and it runs perfectly from there on. However, as I am working with svn, every `svn update` restores some of the deleted files and symlinks while a full `make` restores the rest of the deleted files and symlinks; and Eclipse chokes again.

So I would like to force Eclipse not to scan specific subdirectories of the project, as if the directory never existed for Eclipse in the first place. Any ideas?

Perhaps playing with samba so that the affected dirs are not accessible (but without changing permissions on the dirs themselves) would help, is that possible? That is, if `~/project` is shared, can I make `~/project/subdir` inaccessible without changing its file permissions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Project Properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters -> Add
```

Then under `Filter type` select `Exclude all`, `Applies to: Folders` and enter your folder name which you want to be excluded.